# timeout javascript test - rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I am using `capybara` and `rspec` to test my rails app. Everything is fine, but when I test `javascript` it takes some `40s` to have some response. So I tried, to change

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

and then

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

but I have the same delay of response. So I thought it was an test issue, but I put some test as simple as

```
describe "js test", js: true do
  it "tests javascript" do
    visit root_path
  end
end
```

The use of `poltergeist` throws

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:
       Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"visit","args":["http://127.0.0.1:54218/"]}
```

but I don't think it is a poltergeist issue since any use of capybara driver resolves to `40s` response

Then I tried `spring` and `zeus`, without speeding up the process no success. How can I fix that ?

Comment: did it reset_session ?

Comment: @RajarshiDas what do you mean ?

Comment: `Capybara.reset_sessions!` or `after { page.driver.reset! }`

Comment: @RajarshiDas none of your propositions worked...

Comment: if it is a case of 40 s second then why you did not set default time out of capybara > 40 s

Comment: `Capybara.default_wait_time = 45`

Comment: @RajarshiDas I know about that but I can't wait 45 seconds each time  I want to pass a javascript test !

Comment: @RajarshiDas I also temporarily deleted all the javascript plugin, perhaps there was an external call, but it didn't change anything

Comment: If you know then why you write this  `when I test javascript it takes some 40s to have some response. So I tried, to change` :)

Comment: @RajarshiDas i changed my settings to `Capybara.javascript_driver = :rack_test` and now it is working just fine, how can you explain that ?

Comment: In my case `poltergeist` working like a charm